# Take Screenshot with Tizen SDK

Tags: tizen

Is it possible to take a screenshot with the Tizen SDK similarly to taking one with the Android SDK?
The most I've found is using sdb on the command line, but I'd much prefer a graphical option.

I've googled around for this, but there have been very few relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something quck like click. you can use following one line command:

```
cd ~; fn=$(date "+ screen-%H-%M-%S"); sdb shell xwd -root -out /tmp/"$fn".xwd;  sdb pull /tmp/"$fn".xwd ~/;  convert "$fn".xwd  "$fn".png
```

What it does?

```
cd ~                                     # go to you home directory
fn=$(date "+ screen-%H-%M-%S")           # create variable for file name in bash
sdb shell xwd -root -out /tmp/"$fn".xwd  # open shell and run command to save screenshot
sdb pull /tmp/"$fn".xwd ~/               # copy created file into your home directory
convert "$fn".xwd  "$fn".png             # converting xwd to png in your home
```

; - separator between bash commands

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to adapt this a bit for a windows host, but I'll definitely try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The method can be found here. There is no graphic method currently according to the Tizen IRC channel.
http://seoz.egloos.com/3940763

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Tizen emulator, you can take a screen capture by right-clicking on the emulator then select [Advanced] > [Screen Shot].

If you are using Tizen device, push the power button and the volume down button at the same time.

Comment: This doesn't work for all Tizen devices unfortunately. The Samsung Gear 2, for instance, does not have a physical volume key.

Comment: The power + volume down button does not unfortunately work with a 32" SamsungTV running the newest version of Tizen.