# How to take a screenshot Pro-grammatically and download it in png format?

Tags: format, png, screenshot, tizen

I have built a Tizen app in which i put one background image and one text view on that background. So, i want to merge both view and make png image which user can download.

Answer (score 0):

So far I could found, there's [**EFL UTIL SCREENSHOT**](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__EFL__UTIL__SCREENSHOT__MODULE.html&langredirect=1) API to capture screen from Tizen Native App, but the problem is it uses platform level privilege and this can't be used in 3rd party app unfortunately. You may use sdb shell commands according to [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292047/take-screenshot-with-tizen-sdk) rather than API calls from your app.

Comment: There is no any privilage for screenshot. But as i got an answer from your side that i can not use it for third party application.
So, is there any other way to take a pic of current mobile screen and download as image?

Comment: As far as I know currently this functionality is unavailable what you are expecting above.